# Jenkins using wrong version of Ruby(rvm)

Tags: jenkins, rvm, jenkins-plugins

Have next situation:

- Using jenkins
- Installed rvm with different ruby versions(2+)
- Installed [rvm plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RVM+Plugin)

Enabled option "Run the build in a RVM-managed environment" in "Build Environment" with ruby version `ruby-2.3.0@global`

Now about problem. After each starting of jenkins job I can see next output:

```
Capturing environment variables produced by 'rvm use ruby-2.3.0@global'
$ bash -c export
[workspace] $ bash -c " source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use --install --create ruby-2.3.0@global && export > rvm.env"
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0 with gemset global
...
```

And seems everything should works ok.
But in fact jenkins use `ruby-2.2.0` because below in log I found this:

```
+++ __path_to_ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
+++ [[ -z /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby ]]
+++ [[ /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby != \/\u\s\r\/\l\o\c\a\l\/\r\v\m* ]]
+++ [[ /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby == \/\u\s\r\/\l\o\c\a\l\/\r\v\m\/\b\i\n\/\r\u\b\y ]]
+++ [[ /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby == \/\u\s\r\/\l\o\c\a\l\/\r\v\m* ]]
+++ [[ -z /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0 ]]
+++ [[ -z /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global ]]
...
```

And next problem which stems from here:

```
Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

Also if I type `ruby -v` command in "Execute shell" area - then in log I see this

```
+ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
```

I also tried to start command `rvm use ruby-2.3.0` directly in "Execute shell".

Also I added this into `/var/lib/jenkis/.bashrc`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

And tried to change `$HOME/.rvm` to `/usr/local/rvm`

But everytime result the same. Jenkins does not use ruby-2.3.0

Please help me figure out what did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem too. It turned out that there is an issue if you install rvm as root. We had to fully uninstall rvm and reinstall as the jenkins user, after which the plugin correctly loaded rubies.

You can detect this problem by listing the contents of the directory pointed by Jenkins's $HOME variable. If there is no .rvm directory then you may need to reinstall.